# Hosting Nodejs in Cpanel- Enter to the virtual environment

Tags: node.js, cpanel, shared-hosting

[image]

what does these command means?
Secondly my nodejs RestAPI is working fine with local machine - but not working once i deploy it to server using nodejs cpanel.
Local postman
[image]

while in actual server getting "**Cannot GET /apps/api/product/all**"   -- where my domainName/apps represents "Application URL" in the Cpanel.

Answer (score 1):

little advice....push your project to git then pull it to your server. all dependencies on your machine will be ignored then in the server you can run install updated packages and compatible with your servers Operating system then start the server. fixes most of the version dependency problems you will keep facing. This is the ideal concept not a straight answer